# Have JS APIs return a polyfilled DOM node

Tags: javascript, html, polyfills

I am using the `<data>` element in HTML, which has decent support, but not sufficient for my purposes. The *only* extra functionality in `HTMLDataElement` is a getter for `value`, which returns the respective attribute.

Of course this is trivial to implement, just use the following code (after feature detection, of course)

```
class HTMLDataElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    get value() {
        return this.getAttribute(`value`);
    }
}
```

This works great. Only one problem: when using native APIs such as `getElementById`, `querySelector`, etc., the returned Node is not of instance `HTMLDataElement`. How can I make it so, if this is even possible?

To be clear, I'd like to be able to do `document.querySelector('foo').value`, which would act the same with or without browser support for `<data>`.

(I'm well aware that I can just use `.getAttribute('value')` instead of `.value`. The point is I don't want to.)

Comment: You would have to use `document.registerElement('x-foo');`, but the dash in between is required, so... I don’t really know how to make polyfill. If you find a way tell us.

Comment: @Akxe That's my problem. I'm almost certain it's possible, since I've dealt with similar situations before. But it it's a custom element - it is standardized.

Comment: @Akxe - if you have `document.registerElement` chances are you also have `<data>` :p according to compatibility tables for the two "features"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reaching out to Jonathan Neal* on Twitter, he provided a great example of how this can be done.

```js
if (!this.HTMLDataElement) {
    this.HTMLDataElement = this.HTMLUnknownElement;

    const valueDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLDataElement.prototype, 'value');

    Object.defineProperty(
        HTMLDataElement.prototype,
        'value',
        valueDescriptor || {
            get() {
                return 'DATA' === this.nodeName && this.getAttribute('value');
            }
        }
    );
}

console.log('data:', document.querySelector('data').value);

console.log('xdata:', document.querySelector('xdata').value);
```

```html
<data value="this should work">
<xdata value="this should not work">
```

* For the unfamiliar, Jonathan Neal is large contributor of PostCSS plugins, and has created many JavaScript polyfills himself.